# Why invoke Thread.currentThread.interrupt() in a catch InterruptException block?

Tags: java, multithreading

Why invoke the method `Thread.currentThread.interrupt()` in the catch block?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

This is done to *keep state*.

When you catch the `InterruptedException` and swallow it, you essentially prevent any higher-level methods/thread groups from noticing the interrupt. Which may cause problems.

By calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`, you set the interrupt flag of the thread, so higher-level interrupt handlers will notice it and can handle it appropriately.

[Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) discusses this in more detail in *Chapter 7.1.3: Responding to Interruption*. Its rule is:

> Only code that implements a thread's interruption policy may swallow an interruption request. General-purpose task and library code should never swallow interruption requests.

Comment: In [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) it's stated that _"By convention, any method that exits by throwing an `InterruptedException` **clears interrupt status** when it does so._ I think that this makes the answer clearer in terms of _why_ you need to preserve interrupt status.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `interrupt()` call is the only way to *set* the interrupted flag once you received notification about this state through the other "delivery mechanism" - the `InterruptedException` and wish or cannot re-throw it.

Comment: what do you mean by `higher-level methods/thread groups`?

Answer (score 81):

I think this code sample makes things a bit clear.
The class which does the job :

```
public class InterruptedSleepingRunner implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doAPseudoHeavyWeightJob();
    }

    private void doAPseudoHeavyWeightJob() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            // You are kidding me
            System.out.println(i + " " + i * 2);
            // Let me sleep <evil grin>
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("Thread interrupted\n Exiting...");
                break;
            } else {
                sleepBabySleep();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void sleepBabySleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Main` class:

```
public class InterruptedSleepingThreadMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new InterruptedSleepingRunner());
        thread.start();
        // Giving 10 seconds to finish the job.
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        // Let me interrupt
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Try calling interrupt without setting the status back.

Comment: so the conclusion is ??

Comment: Thanks.  I see what you mean now:  https://repl.it/@djangofan/InterruptedThreadExample

Comment: I think he means that `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` allows you to exit out of thread faster, hence when `InterruptedException e` is caught, the thread is stopped then and there. Whereas if `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` is not used, thread keeps executing..

Comment: That's not what the example depicts. If you swallow interrupt, the outside function will not exit and will continue doing `sleepBabySleep`

Answer (score 23):

Note:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

**How do I stop a thread that waits for long periods (e.g., for input)?**

> For this technique to work, it's critical that any method that catches an interrupt exception and is not prepared to deal with it immediately reasserts the exception. We say reasserts rather than rethrows, because it is not always possible to rethrow the exception. ***If the method that catches the InterruptedException is not declared to throw this (checked) exception, then it should "reinterrupt itself" with the following incantation:***

```
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

***This ensures that the Thread will reraise the InterruptedException as soon as it is able.***

Answer (score 3):

I would consider it a bad practice or at least a bit risky.
Usually higher level methods do not perform blocking operations and they will never see `InterruptedException` there. If you mask it in every place you perform interruptible operation, you will never get it.

The only rationale for `Thread.currentThread.interrupt()` and not raising any other exception or signaling interrupt request in any other way (e.g. setting `interrupted` local variable variable in a thread's main loop) is the situation where you really can't do anything with the exception, like in the `finally` blocks.

See Péter Török's answer, if you want to better understand implications of the `Thread.currentThread.interrupt()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Refer from java doc

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), join(),
>   sleep(long), then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an InterruptedException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an I/O operation, the thread's interrupt
>   status will be set, and the thread will receive a
>   ClosedByInterruptException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in a Selector then the thread's interrupt
>   status will be set and it will return immediately from the selection
>   operation.
>
> If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt
>   status will be set.

So, if you change the sleepBabySleep() method in @Ajay George Answer to I/O operation or just a sysout, you don't have to set the status back to stop the program. (BTW, they don't even throw InterruptedException)

Just like @Péter Török said => This is done to keep state. (And particular for method that will throw InterruptedException)