# Thread.sleep() in an EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I know that messing with threads inside an EJB is a big no-no, but I would just like to ask for advice on how handle this case. My EJB is calling an external Web service which may sometimes return a "busy" status. When that happens, I would like to wait for a while and then  resubmit the request using the same data as before.

What would be the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the [EJB restrictions FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/restrictions-142267.html) it specifically states that you

> should not create or manage threads

And putting a thread to sleep counts as "managing" it.

In your case, when the web service returns a "busy" status, you could schedule a job to retry sending the message at a later point in time, for instance by using the [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). The execution would end there, and any further processing should be delegated to the job scheduler.

Comment: You could also use built-in Java EE timers support.

Comment: If timers are used for retry, how do you propose to keep/pass the arguments from the original request, in order to reconstruct the request for the second call?

Comment: Invoking a whole new layer, messaging, may solve the problem but I can see this is a heavy handed approach to some cases. What if a thread only sleeps for a few seconds? Even 10 seconds at most. All that infrasture work, setup a queue, JNDI, etc, plus the overhead of context switching, can be too much and too complex. There should be flexibility in the standard to allow waiting if the developer judges it to be a good trade off.

Answer (score 14):

EJB 3.1 brought a new `@Asynchronous` [feature](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1321142/Part-Three-New-Features-in-EJB-31) that you can take advantage of:

```
@Asynchronous
@TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)
public Future<WebServiceResult> callWebService(int retries) {
    WebServiceResult result = webService.call();

    if (!result.equals(BUSY)) {
        return result;
    }

    if (retries <= 0) {
        throw new TooBusyException();
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    return callWebService(retries - 1);
}
```

Then simply call you web service with:

```
Future<WebServiceResult> result = yourEJB.callWebService(1);

// Can do some interesting stuff here.
// ...
// ...

result.get(2, SECONDS);  // Block for up to 2 seconds.
```

As you can see you get configurable number of retries and timeout for free.

How does this differ from just calling `Thread.sleep()`? Returning `Future` is more explicit and manageable. Also I don't think `Thread.sleep()` is that harmful. The only problem is that this EJB instance can now longer be reused by other clients. With `Future` asynchronous invocation happens inside some other EJB and thread pool. As to importance of `Thread#interrupt()` inside the catch block, refer [Why invoke Thread.currentThread.interrupt() when catch any InterruptException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906799/why-invoke-thread-currentthread-interrupt-when-catch-any-interruptexception)

Another idea: use aspect around calling web service, catch `BusyException` once and retry.

Comment: how is it any better than using Thread.sleep() in the called EJB? It's still a violation of the spec - it's just more explicit, but you're blocking 2 EJB instances - the spawned (asynchronous) one and the calling one.

Comment: @PiotrNowicki: you are right. The problem is that the OP *would like to wait for a while*, so some blocking is unavoidable. Of course it would be great to use JMS or some scheduler but then some layer above is needed (see *PeterPeiGuo* answer #1). In general  waiting is always problematic in EE environment.

Comment: Agreed. It could be an asynchronous call straight from the client or pooling on the client-side.

Comment: @Tomasz - I think you've mentioned the best solution, which is to use [MDBs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25221_05/web.1013/b14428/undejbs.htm#CIHGDAGD), especially as the OP is already using EJBs, and so therefore has some familiarity with them.

Comment: If you absolutely need to use `Thread#sleep()`, then by all means wrap it in a `try-catch` on `InterruptedException` and inside the catch, do `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` to guarantee proper handling of interrupted state by the container. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906799/why-invoke-thread-currentthread-interrupt-when-catch-any-interruptexception Edit: I see that you're not active anymore for almost 2 years. I'll edit the answer myself to prevent copypaste programmers from running into trouble.

Comment: The example looks like a misuse of async functionality. Why write code if all it will do is wait? If waiting is the result of using async, it's wasted effort, just use a plain sync call. On the other hand, if useful work will happen if not blocking, then async is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

But an external web service is external and you are opening a network connection to it and you wish to do some management stuff.  This is what JCA is for, not EJB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion(or alternative way) with simple control's pool:

1 - Pass your context(EJB) as a parameter to your method(rest endpoint, scheduler, default's methods)

2 - Control the state with complementary scheduler or entity flags

3 - Be careful with the volume of data/processing

4 - Recommendations: Metrics, logs, and tests, tests, tests are strongly recommended

5 - This code is on SpringBoot but was tested in Jboss(with modifications) under EJB Context - Test carefully

6 - Use/modify as you wish: (send suggestions/comments)

BaseControlExecutor.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;


public class BaseControlExecutor {

    private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor poolExec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);

    public void execWithTimeout(final Runnable runnable, long timeout,
            TimeUnit timeUnit) throws Exception {
        execWithTimeout(new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                runnable.run();
                return null;
            }
        }, timeout, timeUnit);
    }

    public <T> T execWithTimeout(Callable<T> callable, long timeout,    TimeUnit timeUnit) throws Exception {

        final Future<T> future = poolExec.submit(callable);

        try {
            return future.get(timeout, timeUnit);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            future.cancel(true);
            throw e;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            Throwable t = e.getCause();
            if (t instanceof Error) {
                throw (Error) t;
            } else if (t instanceof Exception) {
                throw (Exception) t;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EndpointControlRest.java

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/report")
@Api(tags = "Endpoint of Future")
public class EndpointControlRest extends BaseControlExecutor {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EndpointControlRest.class);

    //single metric of execution
    protected final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping(path = "/withThread", produces = { "application/json" })
    @ApiOperation(value = "Return Hello count.")
    public String greeting() {

        Long countRunner = counter.incrementAndGet();
        String json = ""; //or EJB context to use in Thread - becareful

        new Thread(() -> {

            try {
                execWithTimeout(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Instant start = Instant.now();
                        logger.info("Report init - " + countRunner);

                        //generating reports
                        generateBackgroundReport(json);

                        logger.info("Report End - " + countRunner);

                        Instant finish = Instant.now();
                        long timeElapsed = Duration.between(start, finish).toMillis();

                        logger.info("###DEBUG - " + countRunner + " - OK |Time exe: " + timeElapsed);

                    }
                }, 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                logger.info("###DEBUG - " + countRunner + " - Timeout - " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.info("###DEBUG - " + countRunner + " - Exception - " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }).start();

        logger.info("####DEBUG - Rest call released");
        return "Hello " + countRunner;
    }

    public String generateBackgroundReport(String json){

        //simulating work
        Long x = 0L;
        for(Long i = 0L; i < 1000000000L; i ++){
            x = i + 1;
        }
        logger.info("####DEBUG -report: " + x);
        return "OK";
    }
}
```