# Thread safety implications of Spring DI

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, thread-safety

In my contrived example, what are the implications for thread safety with regard to the list of teamMembers?

Can I rely on the state of the list as seen by the `run()` method to be consistent?

Assuming

1. the `setATeamMembers` method is called only once, by spring when it is creating the `ATeamEpisode` bean
2. the `init` method is called by spring (init-method) after #1
3. the `ATeamMember` class is immutable

   - Do I need to declare the `teamMembers` `volatile` or similar?
   - Are there any other hideous problems with this approach that I'm
     overlooking?

Apologies if this is obvious, or a clear failure to rtfm

Thanks and regards

Ed

```java
package aTeam;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class ATeamEpisode implements Runnable{

    private List<ATeamMember> teamMembers;

    /* DI by spring */
    public void setATeamMembers(List<ATeamMember> teamMembers){
        this.teamMembers = new ArrayList<ATeamMember>(teamMembers);    
    }

    private Thread skirmishThread;

    public synchronized void init(){
        System.out.println("Starting skirmish");
        destroy();
        (skirmishThread = new Thread(this,"SkirmishThread")).start();
    }
    public synchronized void destroy(){
        if (skirmishThread != null){
            skirmishThread.interrupt();
            skirmishThread=null;
        }
    }

    private void firesWildlyIntoTheAir(ATeamMember teamMember){
        System.out.println(teamMember.getName()+" sprays the sky..");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            while(! Thread.interrupted()){
                firesWildlyIntoTheAir(teamMembers.get(rnd.nextInt(teamMembers.size())));
                Thread.sleep(1000 * rnd.nextInt(5));
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("End of skirmish");
            /* edit as per Adam's suggestion */
           // Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Who executes the Runnable? And who interrupts it? Normally setter-based injection follows the construction, so I would say run() is safe here. But there are other issues with your code. For instance, calling Thread.currentThread().interrupt() after the thread was interruped.

Comment: Thanks Adam, interesting point, cf. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906799)  Is it ok to swallow the exception here?

Comment: it makes sense in sub-routines called from run() that cannot throw checked InterruptedException, but not in run() directly where the thread (runnable) should just exit

Comment: yes, since you just want to exit there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If, as you say, setATeamMembers is called only once, and no other part of your code either replaces this collection, then there is no point in making it volatile. Volatile indicates that a member can be **written** by different threads.

Considering no part of your code seems to be updating this collection either, you might want to consider making the collection explicitly *unmodifiable*, for instance by using Collections.unmodifiableList(). This makes it clear to you, and others, that this collection won't be modified, and will throw a big fat exception in your face if you try to modify it regardless.

Spring's lazy initialization is, AFAIR, thread safe.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe. The `List` interface as such isn't thread safe and no matter what you do, it can't be made thread safe *on the consumer side*.

What you need to do is create a thread safe list (the Java runtime has a couple of implementations) and use one of those for the `teamMembers` bean.

Accessing the bean via the field `teamMembers` isn't an issue because the other threads don't create a new instance, they change the *state* (ie. the data inside of) the `teamMembers` bean.

So the bean must make sure that changes to its *internal structure* are correctly synchronized.

In your case, you will need a special list implementation which returns a random element from the list. Why? Because the value for `teamMembers.size()` can have changed when `teamMembers.get()` is called.

A simple way to achieve this is to wrap all method calls in this code:

```
 synchronized(teamMembers) { ... }
```

But you must be sure that you really caught all of them. The most simple way to achieve that is, as I said above, to write your own list which offers all the special methods that you need. That way, you can use locks or `synchronized` inside of the methods as necessary.

Comment: No part of his code updates the list, so it isn't really an issue unless we assume that pieces of the code are missing. If the list is updated, then yes, the call should be synchronized.

Comment: @Marble: Eventually, he will start to update the list and then, he'll have forgotten where he used calls which he should have protected with a lock. So it's better to make sure he synchronizes too much until he starts to understand what he's doing.