# Why main thread has no shutdown method

Tags: program-entry-point, shutdown, executorservice

When I am running a main thread as in a `public static void main` method, the thread terminates when the method completes. I don't do anything explicit to shutdown the thread.
Why then in case of `ExecutorService`. we have a shutdown() method? Why cannot we just let the thread(s) managed by `ExecutorService`  run to completion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The invocation of shutdown method just means that no new tasks will be accepted by the executor. You can give a timeout to the running tasks(to run to completion) submitted to the executor.

```
executor.shutdown();
try {
    //blocks until all tasks have finished or timeout occurs
    executor.awaitTermination(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS , Long.MAX_VALUE);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  //Take some action at least Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Comment: So the shutdown methods will not terminate all the worker threads in the pool?

Comment: Also can you explain why you did:Thread.currentThread().interrupt()... why are you sending an Interuupt inside an InterruptedException?

Comment: No, they will stop accepting tasks by throwing `RejectedExecutionException`. The interrupt part is already discussed - Don't swallow interrupts(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906799/why-invoke-thread-currentthread-interrupt-when-catch-any-interruptexception)