# Should we really interrupt the current thread after catching InterruptedException?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have code, which needs to wait a while as a part of busy-wait (due to legacy code I cannot change that much). I've read the reasoning why I should do that here [1] and [2], and it's presented as no-brainer rule of thumb. Do this always. IIUC it's sold as necessary because some code higher up call stack can be doing  things like:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
```

and without calling

```
Thread.currentThread().interrupt()
```

or rethrowing it would fail.

Now back to my case. I called minuscule method sleep. If I was woken up in the middle of busy wait, I don't care, I will sleep again if I have to. If there actually is a code interested in thread interrupted flag, I definitely don't want it to kick in, because I don't want to halt this operation, and in this case, swallowing without retry and without setting flag seems to be correct operation, however I did not see any mention, that swallow can be correct reaction in some situation.

- [1] https://dzone.com/articles/why-do-we-need-threadcurrentthreadinterrupt-in-int
- [2] https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html?ca=drs-

Comment: What do you mean by "woken up in the middle"? You are woken by somebody calling `interrupt()`. The expected reaction to this is to stop what you are doing and kill your work cleanly. Why do you feel like somebody called `interrupt()` and didn't really mean it?

Comment: @RealSkeptic perhaps he was thinking about the elusive *spurious interrupts*. If it's legacy code and the operation is something that isn't easy to shutdown correctly while it's running, I would swallow it (and assume it's spurious). But I don't know anything about the codebase, so why should you listen to me?

Comment: You can check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57576092/4956907) to similiar question here. Maybe it will be handy to you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good book on concurrency in Java: [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601). In chapter 7, section 7.1.3 there is this text:

> Only code that implements a thread's interruption policy may swallow an interruption request. General-purpose task and library code should never swallow interruption requests.

So, it *is* possible to swallow the interrupt in some situations.