# Can I use "Thread.currentThread().interrupt()" when I want to stop execution inside a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Used for thread control
You are using "CountDownLatch", and at the end you are using "latch.countDown()" to control the thread.
But if I use "return" to detach a thread during execution like below code,
Since "latch.countDown()" cannot be called, the thread remains waiting. So I want to use "latch.countDown()" and "Thread.currentThread().interrupt()" instead of "return", but I'm wondering if this is the correct way to do it. I'd like some help on what to do if I'm wrong.

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch();

public void run() {
  //....
  if (isNotExist) {
    retrun; //-> instead of "return" Can I use "latch.countDown()" and "Thread.currentThread().interrupt()" together?
  }
  //...
  latch.countDown()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use [`CountdownLatch::countDown`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#countDown()) and then want to wait until the latch releases, we would use [`CountdownLatch::await`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await()). I recommend reading the [full documentation of `CountdownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Calling [`Thread::interrupt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) on the current thread has no apparent effect since the thread is not blocking right now. It would have an effect if the thread was blocked, e.g. by an I/O operation. But then again, if the current thread is blocked, it cannot interrupt itself. It can be used to keep the state. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906799/why-invoke-thread-currentthread-interrupt-in-a-catch-interruptexception-block) by [Hesey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/590091/hesey) and its answers for details.

If we use `return`, we return from the current method. This is a totally different construct than blocking.

Comment: Thank you. happy New Year!!