# InterruptedException Issue on Sonar while getting data from CompletableFuture

Tags: java, exception, sonarqube, completable-future, interrupted-exception

Here inside the for loop I'm trying to get the value from `stringCompletableFutureEntry` which throws the `InterruptedException` and with sonar enabled on this, I am supposed to interrupt the thread when an exception occurs but according to my expectation I should get data for all futures if it's not there than I can use `Optional.empty()` or skip this iteration and move further. How should I get rid of this sonar issue?

```java
private void mapFutures(
      Map<Obj1, CompletableFuture<DummyContainer>> futures, List<DummyStatus> dummyStatusList) {
    for (Map.Entry<Obj1, CompletableFuture<DummyContainer>> stringCompletableFutureEntry :
        futures.entrySet()) {
      try {
        Optional<DummyContainer> dummyContainer =
            Optional.ofNullable(**stringCompletableFutureEntry.getValue().get()**);
        List<Dummy> dummy = null;
        dummy = dummyContainer.map(DummyContainer::getDummyData).orElseGet(() -> null);
        
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(dummy)) {
          dummyStatusList.add(new DummyStatus(stringCompletableFutureEntry.getKey(), dummy.get(0)));
        } else {
          dummyStatusList.add(new DummyStatus(stringCompletableFutureEntry.getKey()));
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // sonar expectation
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried using timeout while getting data e.g.

```java
stringCompletableFutureEntry.getValue().get(Long.parseLong("3000"), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
```

It'll throw a `TimeoutException` once the time threshold is reached.

I'm looking for other Solutions to get rid of `InterruptedException` inside the loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why invoke Thread.currentThread.interrupt() in a catch InterruptException block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906799/why-invoke-thread-currentthread-interrupt-in-a-catch-interruptexception-block)

Comment: @DidierL Since I need to interrupt the thread here, do we have any other approach with which I can avoid getting InterruptedException? I'm using Executor Service and I don't want the output to get effected due to one iteration failure. Please suggest me the  best way to handle it.

Comment: @DidierL I've also tried checking the interrupted flag - if its true used Optional.empty() but with this I stucked to this Exception -                                                     

Interrupted acquiring a permit to retrieve an item from the pool ; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoInterruptedException: Interrupted acquiring a permit to retrieve an item from the pool